# Angular : Image preview not display on (change)="" event

Tags: angular, typescript, image, file-upload

I created Image preview area and file upload input to upload image. i trigger the browse image dialog preview click through the button.

> image.component.html

```
<input class="d-none" type="file" accept="image/*" #file (change)="onImageChanged(file.files)">
<button (click)="file.click()">
   Upload Again
</button>
```

**Image Preview area**

```
 <div class="image-preview">
    <img alt="prescription_image" [src]="image_url">
  </div>
```

> image.component.ts

```
image_url: any;

onImageChanged(files) {

if (files.length === 0) {
  return;
}

let mimeType = files[0].type;
if (mimeType.match(/image\/*/) == null) {
  console.log('Only images are supported.');
  return;
}

let reader = new FileReader();
this.selected_file = files;
reader.onload = () => {
  this.image_url = reader.result;
};
reader.readAsDataURL(this.selected_file[0]);
  }
```

I have a problem on previewing image properly, image is preview when i click upload again button. could any one explain me the why the image not preview after i select.

Comment: We need debug for this. I think the problem comes from `onload` callback is not executed inside zone ==> no detect changes run. From Angular 9 (Ivy), it is easy to debug with `ng.applyChanges` to see if it's the problem.

Comment: i debug the `onload`  method its initialize the value of selected image. issue is image not display the ```src``` value on that time.

Comment: A detection change need to run in order to display the image. If you can make a stackblitz, I can look at it for you.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nkk9ap here is the stackblitz link. but it work perfecly.

Comment: So, it's working. Do you have `OnPush` change detection strategy activated in your component?

Comment: no i didn't added that.

Comment: I can't really help you if we can't reproduce the bug. The only thing I can think of, it's OnPush strategy. Search for `OnPush` in your whole project to see if you found anything.